# Regex for multiple conditions

Tags: regex

I want regx for following condition

> 1.Combination of Letters and Digits should accept.
>
> 2.Combination of Letters and symbols should accept.
>
> 3.Only Letters should accept.
>
> 4.Only digits should not accept.
>
> 5.Only Symbols should not accept.
>
> 6.Combination of letters,digits,symbols should accept.

I am trying like this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+\s*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

What is wrong.

Comment: Do not see anything about digits or symbols in your code.

Comment: Where in your expression are you matching those digits you speak of? Why are you matching spaces?

Comment: What RegEx flavor you got? Does it support [`lookaheads`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this regex

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV2hN5/3)

Comment: @#%#$^23532dfgdfg -  Combination of letters,digits,symbols should accept. -- should have to work